# Pyomo- Constrint of CVPR

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm trying to create a constraint

```
def rest1(modelo, i):
    return sum(sum(modelo.M[r, i, j] for j in modelo.j) for r in modelo.r if i!=j)==1
```

modelo.restr1 = pyEnv.Constraint(modelo.i, rule= rest1)

but i get this error:

*ValueError: Invalid constraint expression. The constraint expression resolved to a trivial Boolean (False) instead of a Pyomo object. Please modify your rule to return Constraint.Infeasible instead of False.*

modelo.M is a Var

Comment: Please properly format and indent your code.

Comment: collapse your `sum(sum())` statement into one `sum(... for i in ... for j in ... if i !=j ) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to provide a minimal working example so that community members can attempt to produce your error.

I imagine the issue stems from one of two reasons:

1. The object `modelo.M` is a `Param` and the sum over the specified indices is a constant that is not equal to 1 as required.
2. The sum is over an empty set. Sums over empty sets evaluate to a constant 0, and 0 != 1.